# Remove repeated records using the greatest date (Linq Query)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a table with repetitive values and I would like to remove the repeated records using the greatest date.

```
Id| PId | StartDate              | RegNo |
 -------------------------------------------
 1| A08 |2018-02-07 00:00:00.000 | OLP009|
 2| A08 |2018-02-09 00:00:00.000 | OLP009|
 3| A08 |2018-07-17 00:00:00.000 | OLP009|
 4| A08 |2019-01-09 00:00:00.000 | OLP009|
 5| A31 |2018-01-09 00:00:00.000 | KP9110|
 6| A31 |2018-01-17 00:00:00.000 | KP9110|
```

My linq query looks something like this

```
IEnumerable<Credentials> credentials = await this.context.Credentials.SqlQuery("SELECT Id, PId, StartDate, RegNo FROM dbo.regTbl").ToListAsync();
```

I am trying to achieve something like this from my select linq statement

```
Id| PId | StartDate              | RegNo |
 ------------------------------------------
 4| A08 |2019-01-09 00:00:00.000 | OLP009|
 6| A31 |2018-01-17 00:00:00.000 | KP9110|
```

I am using Entity Framework Version 6.2

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server 2017

Comment: I can help you providing the SQL statement, you can then convert that into LINQ statement.

Comment: please provide any answer @mkRabbani

Comment: Answer added @JohnNyingi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the SQL statement for your requirement. You can now convert it into LINQ statement.

```
SELECT A.ID,A.PID,A.startdate,A.regno 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY startdate DESC) RN, 
    * 
    FROM yourtable
)A WHERE RN = 1
```